# php: create directory on form submit?

Tags: php, mkdir

I am wondering what I am doing wrong. I'm inside of PATH and I want to create a folder inside of PATH. I want to check if the folder already exists and, if not, create one. Getting the name of the folder from an input field with name of "dirname".

```
if (isset($_POST['createDir'])) {
    //get value of inputfield
    $dir = $_POST['dirname'];
    //set the target path ??
    $targetfilename = PATH . '/' . $dir;
    if (!file_exists($dir)) {
        mkdir($dir); //create the directory
        chmod($targetfilename, 0777); //make it writable
    }
}
```

Comment: A bucket of security worms I tell you...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It might be a good idea to make sure that the directory you are handling is indeed a directory. This code works... edit as you please.

```
define("PATH", "/home/born05/htdocs/swish_s/Swish");

$test = "set";
$_POST["dirname"] = "test";


if (isset($test)) {
  //get value of inputfield
  $dir = $_POST['dirname'];
  //set the target path ??

$targetfilename = PATH . '/' . $dir;

if (!is_file($dir) && !is_dir($dir)) {
    mkdir($dir); //create the directory
    chmod($targetfilename, 0777); //make it writable
}
else
{
    echo "{$dir} exists and is a valid dir";
}
```

### Good luck!

Edited: comment was a good hint ;)

Comment: If there is a file named $dir when is_dir is run, it'll return false, because it's not a dir, but the subsequent mkdir will fail because the file already exists. It's better to use file_exists.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use

```
!is_dir($dir)
```

instead of

```
!file_exists($dir)
```

it's not a file, it's a directory!

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [is_dir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php).

Answer (score 0):

@codeworxx file_exists can be used to check a directory as well..

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: It can, but a file can also be disguised as a directory if it has no extension. So it will return true for file_exists but false for is_dir. ;)