# How can I create a new Directory on my website from the Clients computer so they can upload unique data to me?

Tags: php, javascript, html, directory, client-server

Can somebody please give me the code to be able to create a new folder on my website from a Clients computer using a submit button? PHP, JAVA or HTML

Comment: Not possible due to security restrictions. You'd have to build an ActiveX component or a JavaScript applet with local rights to do this

Comment: NOt at all Pekka. He wants to create it on the SERVER.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a directory on the server with

```
<?php
  mkdir("/path/to/my/dir", 0700);
?>
```

Have a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

You need to have the right permission on your path. Folder should be owend by webserver user.

For a full example have a look at this previous [asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343446/php-create-directory-on-form-submit) or this [blog post](http://slunked.com/blog/2010/01/create-directory-php-user-input/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Use php [mkdir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)

```
<?php
mkdir("/path/to/my/dir", 0700);
?>
```